# Is it possible to predict the operating state of a power system (using MATLAB) if I have calculated the voltages at all nodes by state estimation?

Tags: power, control, control-system, matlab

If I have calculated all the node voltages by state estimation, is it possible to predict which operating state my system is at? By operating state, I mean any of the following:
                                                                                    [image]

In addition to being able to say which operating state my system is at currently, I want my code to be able to say if there is a risk of heading towards an emergency or 'in extremis' state. I know my question should've been clearer, but I don't know enough at the moment. It would be great if someone could suggest an algorithm and the data I would need to execute the algorithm.

Comment: These 'operating states'. Are they something you've defined, or are you in some well-known to you but as yet unidentified to us discipline like rail transport, or medical theatre electronics? If the former, then this is an exercise in tautology. Normal is defined as voltage in this range, I've measured a voltage, can I tell if it's in this range? Well, duh, yes. If the latter, then it's time to spill enough information for us to share the documentation.

Comment: @Neil_UK The states are defined. I wanted to know how I can 'predict' if the system will head towards a state of risk. By judging if the voltage falls within a certain range I can tell if it is at risk currently but how can I predict its future operating state? Is that possible? What additional information will I require?

Comment: You'll need information about the way the system evolves. What's the system? If it's a battery driving a load, then you can assume the battery voltage will fall over time. If it's a collection of generators feeding a population watching a football match, then you can assume there will be a load surge at half-time when everybody switches their kettles on, and you can assume virtually nothing about the rest of the time. What does your system do?

Comment: to put it another way, is your system predictable? If so, you can predict it. If not, then ...

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thanks!